# Regular expression for any double type number

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to do the following:

```
myVar = q.match(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+/);
```

However, when I type a decimal, myVar doesn't pick up the decimal until after I type decimal values.

```
Entered 3, myVar = 3
Entered ., myVar = 3
Entered 3, myVar 3.3
```

How do I modify this so myVar would equal 3. at the second step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you also want to match something like `.3`, right? But you have to be sure your regex doesn't match a decimal point by itself `.`. So you could do it with these alternations:

```
myVar = q.match(/\d+\.\d*|\.?\d+/);
```

`\d+\.\d*` matches `3.`, `3.3`, `3.33` etc.

`\.?\d+` matches `.3`, `.33`, `3`, `33`, etc.

**ALTERNATE:**
If you need to allow commas for thousands, millions, etc., use the following:

```
myVar = q.match(/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d*|\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*|\.\d+/);
```

`\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d*` matches `3.`, `3.3`, `3.33`, `3,333.3` etc.

`\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*` matches `3`, `33`, `3,333` etc.

`\.\d+` matches `.3`, `.33`, etc.

Comment: thank you! How would I match commas into that expression if I wanted to accept 3,300.33 for example?

Comment: To be precise, you want to accept commas only when followed by three digits, and that combination can happen any number of times: `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*`. Use that in place of the `\d+` before the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the + after [0-9] it means 1 or more occurrence.  Try using *. It should work.

```
myVar = q.match(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*/);
```

Can be simplified to:

```
myVar = q.match(/[0-9]*\.[0-9]*/);
```

Problem is it is looking for atleast 1 number after the . In your case you want 0 or more.

Comment: This regex works, but it also matches `.` by itself. I provided an alternate solution that corrects for that.

Comment: @BrianStephens You are correct.  If you want it to not match `.` by itself then you should use BrianStephens solution.